# Is there any way to work in the same py file where I already created concat file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I am new in pandas, so please help me with this question.
I created concatenate file from 5 csv files as follows:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import csv

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\csv files")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])

combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Now I want to work with that file, but when I type some command, for example `print(combined_csv.isnull().sum())` the program starts from the beginning and my already created combined csv file append twice (my combined file consists of 8040 raws, after that it becomes 16080 raws) then gives the result of the required command `combined_csv.isnull().sum()` .

I understand that it is normal, because I run program twice, but is there any way to solve this problem not using file as a command line argument, maybe something write in the code?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work more interactively with data (without restarting a python script again and again), you can use `ipython` (https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html) or the even more convenient browser app `jupyter lab` (https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).